# can't login to any account in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I just installed mysql on a mac and I can't seem to access any accounts from there.

I used the commands :

```
shell> mysql -u root -p
password:
```

and since I have not given one I let it go blank and I get an error saying incorrect password.

I can login using just

```
shell> mysql
```

buy I can't seem to be able to change passwords or even look at all the accounts in mysql.users.

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'users'

What do I do to resolve this issue and how do I use a software like sequel pro with the database?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems, you dont have all the privileges for localhost@root, to get all the privileges run the below command.

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by 'password' with grant option
```

in MySQL command prompt and you will have all the previleges to access the localhost as root.

use this command to set the password for MySQL

```
mysqladmin -u root password “newpassword”;
```

Example `mysqladmin -u root password adhfhuef34;`

You will also want to restart the database server after running this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

If this Dint work, Try

```
$ mysql -u root
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

Comment: i get this error:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: i still get the error

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql Admin -u root password newpassword' at line 1

and for the second one


ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: i am using a vm and installed it in linux so its working there but thanks for all the help